# How to set dynamic HyperLinks ordered into a table cell

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, repeater

I have an structure like this in aspx.

```
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Values: 
                        <asp:Repeater ID="repeater1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="repeater1_ItemDataBound" OnItemCommand="repeater1_ItemCommand">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:HyperLink ID="hlk" runat="server" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:Repeater>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

In the databound event I am binding this hyperlink and when I add many values, (Hyperlinks) my table starts to grow horizontally and I want when there is no more space in the cell they must continue binding in the next row.

So what am I missing in the html structure to have this behaviour?

This is what is happening

```
Values: AAA BBB CCCC DDD EEEEE FFF GGG HHH III JJJJJ KKK .....
```

I want this

```
Values: AAA BBB CCCC DDD
        EEEEE FFF GGG HHH
        III JJJJJ KKK ....
        ................
        ..........
```

Comment: with css every thing is possible..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hyperlinks should go in new line if the table is limited in width.

Try to define table/column width  You can try following inline CSS:

```
<head>
    <style>
       table {width: 100%}
       td {width: 20px}
    </style>
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the item template the way you want the structure to be. You need to tell the Repeater to add a row after adding 4 items which needs some manipuation in code. However for your scenario, using a **DataList** would be the best option. You can specify the **RepeatLayout** as Table and set the **RepeatColumns** to as many as you want and it will automatically format the data.

```
<asp:DataList ID="rptLinks" runat="server" RepeatColumns="3" RepeatLayout="Table">
       <ItemTemplate>
              <table width="100%">
                    <tr>
                         <td>
                             <asp:HyperLink ID="hlk" runat="server" />                                                                       
                         </td>                                                                                                                                       
                    </tr>                                                                 
              </table>
        </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```